# Strange reaction when comparing dates with currentDate Swift

Tags: ios, swift, date

I have as the title says a very strange reaction when I compare dates with currentDate.
Here is what happen: 
I do a query to my server to take some dates then I print them so I will be sure that it took them right (and everything is ok). 
Then I print currentDate which is appearing with 3 hours earlier.
Ok I will fix it then I'm saying.
BUT! when I'm trying to compare them I take only the dates that are 20:59 and earlier.

This is my code (`//dateevent are the dates that I recover from server`)

```
if dateevent.earlierDate(self.currentDate).isEqualToDate(self.currentDate){
   print("All dates \(dateevent)")
   if NSCalendar.currentCalendar().isDate(dateevent, equalToDate: self.currentDate, toUnitGranularity: .Day){
     print("here is what it passed from server \(dateevent)")
     print("here is the current date \(self.currentDate)") 
                        }

                    }
```

This is my output

```
All dates 2016-07-28 19:00:00 +0000
here is what it passed from server 2016-07-28 19:00:00 +0000
here is the current date 2016-07-28 13:43:51 +0000

All dates 2016-07-28 19:00:00 +0000
here is what it passed from server 2016-07-28 19:00:00 +0000
here is the current date 2016-07-28 13:43:51 +0000

All dates 2016-07-28 21:00:00 +0000
All dates 2016-07-28 21:00:00 +0000
All dates 2016-07-28 23:30:00 +0000
All dates 2016-07-29 21:00:00 +0000
All dates 2016-07-29 22:30:00 +0000
All dates 2016-07-29 23:00:00 +0000
All dates 2016-07-29 23:00:00 +0000
All dates 2016-07-29 23:30:00 +0000
All dates 2016-07-30 21:00:00 +0000
```

Comment: In what timezone are you?

Comment: I'm in Greece and we have UTC+02:00

Comment: print `currentDate` and `dateevent` before you compare them. It seems obvious that `self.currentDate` has changed. BTW, your first line is easier expressed as `dateevent.compare(self.currentDate) == OrderedDescending `

Comment: ok I will test it tomorrow because I don't have access now (but how can currentdate has changed itself?)

Comment: It works exactly as it should. You're using UTC times on your backend, clear from the `+0000`, and the cutoff for midnight in Greece this time of year is `21:00:00 UTC`.

Comment: As I can see for my results I thought too that 3 hours after 21:00 is counted as the next day but after I printed it was strange because the time is 3 hours back than the current. Anyway is it possible to convert the current time as my actual current time?

Comment: You get the current time as `NSDate.date()`

Comment: @fishinear `NSDate.compare` doesn't do the same thing as `NSCalendar.compare`  The latter allows you to only compare specific portions, in this case comparing the date and ignoring the time, while the former compares the whole date, including time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer of my question!

I found it  [here](https://gist.github.com/kristopherjohnson/dc088c022f11da3fbc54)

What I did is this:

```
let utcCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)
```

Inside viewDidLoad I pu this:

```
utcCalendar!.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")!
```

and finnaly in my statement i put this:

`if self.utcCalendar!.isDate` and so on...

Thank you all for your answers!

EDIT!

If I want to print the date I have to change dateformatter too like this:

```
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")!
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not going to discuss what time zones you should use on the server side, but the most convenient and consistent way is UTC. As you're already using UTC time zones on your server, you need to take this into account when storing dates and times on your server. What I mean with this, is that if you're storing e.g. `2016-07-28 21:00:00 +0000`, it doesn't necessarily translate to `2016-07-28 21:00:00` at your location.

See the following:

```
let time = NSDate()        // Create an object for the current time.

print(time, "\n")          // Sample output: 
                              2016-07-28 15:23:02 +0000
```

The `time` object printed out as it is outputs the current time in UTC. As a reference, the local time zone for me also happens to be UTC+3, so the local time is `2016-07-28 18:23:02 +0300`.

Let's look at a few dates in string format next:

```
let strings = [
    "2016-07-28 19:00:00 +0000",
    "2016-07-28 20:00:00 +0000",
    "2016-07-28 20:59:59 +0000", // Second before midnight, UTC+3.
    "2016-07-28 21:00:00 +0000", // Midnight in UTC+3.
    "2016-07-28 22:00:00 +0000",
    "2016-07-28 23:30:00 +0000",
    "2016-07-28 23:59:59 +0000", // Second before midnight, UTC.
    "2016-07-29 00:00:00 +0000"  // Midnight in UTC.
]
```

And now, let's convert those strings into `NSDate` objects, which again, will remain in the UTC time zone:

```
var dates: [NSDate] = []

for string in strings {
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"
    guard let date = formatter.dateFromString(string) else { continue }
    dates.append(date)
}
```

Next, we'll convert the `NSDate` objects to strings with the local format, which is probably where your confusion stems from:

```
for date in dates {
    print("Current time in UTC: ", time)
    print("Date in UTC:         ", date)

    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
    print("Current local time:  ", formatter.stringFromDate(time))
    print("Date in local time:  ", formatter.stringFromDate(date))
}

// Sample output for the date 2016-07-28 19:00:00 +0000:
// Current time in UTC:  2016-07-28 15:23:02 +0000
// Date in UTC:          2016-07-28 19:00:00 +0000
// Current local time:   2016-07-28 18:23:02
// Date in local time:   2016-07-28 22:00:00
```

Comment: Very good explanation I try to use this as the above answer and I will tell you my results thank you

Answer (score 1):

Greece summertime actually has a 3 hour difference with UTC. So the UTC `2016-07-28 21:00:00 +0000` time and later is actually in the next day in Greece. So if you compare that according to the local (Greece) calendar with:

```
NSCalendar.currentCalendar().isDate(dateevent, equalToDate: self.currentDate, toUnitGranularity: .Day)
```

then it will not compare equal.

If you want to compare according to UTC days instead, then set the timeZone of the calendar object to UTC:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = NSCalender.currentCalendar();
calendar.timeZone = NSTimeZone.timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT(0);
if (calendar.isDate(dateevent, equalToDate: self.currentDate, toUnitGranularity: .Day)) ...
```

If you want to compare according to some other timezone, then you obviously need to set the `timeZone` differently.

---

If you are OK with comparing the dates according to the local timezone, but are simply confused that the dates are printed in UTC, then use the following for converting to a string:

```
NSDateFormatter().stringFromDate(dateevent)
```

Comment: and what have I do?

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: @fishinear Why on earth would you compare all dates in UTC days? Which you aren't even doing with `NSTimeZone.timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT(0)`.

Comment: @xoudini It depends on what the OP actually wants to achieve, which he has not said. In a server application, for example, you usually want to compare the dates in the time zone where the end user is located. Either that, or UTC.

Comment: True, so @mikevorisis, what exactly is your desired end result? Are you actually displaying UTC times outwards or should the dates and times be displayed with the local time zone?

Comment: My server have dates in utc and my application and site is for greece only (for now at least)

Comment: @mikevorisis the question really is: why do want to check whether it is the same day? From the answer to that follows what definition of days to use.

Comment: @xoudini yes! I have some events and I want to show which event is Today (in Greece apparently)

Comment: @mikevorisis In that case, your code is correct, and you are just confused because the dates are printed in UTC. I suggest you check out NSCalendar and NSDateFormatter, they will help you out.

Comment: In that case I suggest manually converting (or using a tool to convert) local times to UTC and store the UTC times on your server. So if the event is at `20:00` in Greece (`+0300`), you should store the time as `17:00 +0000` on your server. This way people in e.g. Rome will see the event as taking place at `19:00 +0200` and everybody is happy.

Comment: I tried to change timezone with dateformatter but nothing changed I will check nscalendar

Comment: @mikevorisis You can't change the time zone on an `NSDate`, since it is only a wrapper for the time interval since the Unix epoch. `NSDate` is always represented in UTC, and must be converted to a string if you want to display it as a local time.